# Mac OS 10.8 Gitlab. Fingerprint cannot be generated

Tags: macos, ssh, gitlab

It is not possible to generate fingerprint in GitLab 6.0.
[image]

I have done the installation on Mac OS 10.8 and a also have checked the installation.

```
$ sudo -u git -H bash -l -c 'bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production'
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.0 ? ... OK (1.7.0)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
post-receive hook up-to-date? ... yes
post-receive hooks in repos are links: ...
Lex Beelen / test ... repository is empty

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... no
Try fixing it:
Redownload the init script
For more information see:
doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
Projects have satellites? ...
Lex Beelen / test ... can't create, repository is empty
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.7.12)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

The installation guide that a use is https://github.com/CiTroNaK/Installation-guide-for-GitLab-on-OS-X .

Is there someone who knows why it's not possible to generate the fingerprint?

I also have checked the /private/tmp map if the key is generated.
And it's.
-rw-------   1 git              wheel  398 10 sep 12:15 gitlab_key_file20130910-59466-bn56ry